# How to integrate AWS Lex Chatbots Voice to Facebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, amazon-lex

I had configured my chatbot using AWS Lex Chatbot service. My main intention to create chatbot is to integrate it to Facebook and the user's communication should possible in both text and voice. I integrated my chatbot to facebook successfully by following steps give in AWS documentation. BUt voice piece was not working on facebook. Please, provide me any suggestions or any reference blogs of integrating lex voice piece to Facebook along with the text.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Messenger doesn't interpret lex responses into Voice responses, at least not yet.

The `event` object received, when accessing Lex from Facebook, will generate `requestAttributes` and those specify the accepted content types under `x-amz-lex:accept-content-types`.

```
"requestAttributes": {  
    "x-amz-lex:accept-content-types": "PlainText"
},
```

As you can see, `PlainText` is the only accepted content-type. Even though Lex has 4 supported message content-types: 'PlainText', 'SSML', 'CustomPayload', and 'Composite'. [See here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-manage-prompts.html#msg-prompts-formats)

From [Facebook Messenger Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages):

> The Messenger Platform allows you to attach assets to messages, including audio, video, images, and files.

Even though Facebook accepts attachments of audio, Lex only sends PlainText or SSML.
Lex does use Facebook's messsage attachments when it sends Response Cards, but the Response Cards can only have a Generic Type, so that it only sends images, not audio files. [See here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_ResponseCard.html)